# Google Sheets sort checked checkboxes relevant data by order

Tags: google-sheets, checkbox, spreadsheet

In my sheet I have checkboxes and item names next to them. Once I check a checkbox, the item name is displayed in the main sheet in column C and the belonging icon in column B. Column E and F are for the buyer name and the price.

Issue is, since the items are automatically sorted A-Z, the  buyer name and price for alot of items messes up once new items are added.

For example an item that starts with a "G" moves automatically one row down once another item is added that starts with any letter before "G".

Is it possible to sort the list by order of addition of the checked checkboxes?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yKYFnWgJN823bd6PjDy-Ozi20gF2UckEUK9I3CXgerI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: you would need a timestamp script

Comment: I was wondering if a workaround with importrange would be possible; I saw in another sheet a formula with that. Like the formula in C3 here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a35eu0HL0rU9MTAf_RGLQhTmuCv4HjyyiQSUB0Qs6J0/edit#gid=2042032526

But I am not sure, if they fill in item names manually

Comment: save the timestamp as a hidden column and sort using that, there's not really another way of doing it

Comment: alright I will try. thanks!